# Better way to stop body from scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to build a layout that, when the sidebar is scrolled, the main content area doesn't scroll along with it when you reach the bottom of the sidebar.

The only way I can think of to achieve this is to add a class to the body/html when hovering over the sidebar, that sets the overflow of the body to hidden, therefor stopping the fly away scrolling.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".sidebar").hover(function () {
                $('body,html').addClass("special-overflow");
            }, function () {
                $('body,html').removeClass("special-overflow");
            });
        });
```

Here's a jsfiddle of the basic layout. http://jsfiddle.net/V7vaK/

The problem with this is the sidebars disappear when you hover the sidebar and it sort of jerks the page around.
I've been googling this for a while now and I can't see, nor can I come up with a better solution.

Can anyone suggest something more elegant than this?

Comment: Even with the fiddle, I don't understand. Your aims need to be better described Andy.

Comment: I believe that if you use a custom JS scrollbar (there's a popular one for jQuery) this will happen whether you want to or not.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot When you scroll to the bottom of the sidebar, the main content starts scrolling down normally, unless you apply overflow:hidden to the body/html. I'm looking for a better solution than I already have, as I'm sure there is one.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood well it may be another approach of what you are trying to do:

http://cdpn.io/uzrpF

I hope it helps!

Miguel.